# Сохранение и загрузка состояния Activity

Tags: java, android, activity, activity-life-cycle, android-shared-preferences

Возможно ли в Android сохранить разметку с значениями в файл, чтобы после можно было её из этого файла потом загрузить?

Допустим, у меня есть main.xml, там 2 `Button` и 20 `TextView`. Для каждого `TextView` я программно написал текст (каждый текст около 20 слов).

Можно ли как-нибудь сохранить это всё и запустить в новом `Activity`? Просто такой же эффект возникает при повороте экрана, эти два метода уже не работают. ((

```
onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
getLastNonConfigurationInstance()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам надо куда-то сохранить строки из `TextView` и восстановить их после поворота активити или передать в другую активити. Для этого есть класс `Bundle`.

В него можно сохранить ваши строки, а потом извлечь.

1. Для сохранения в текущей активити используйте метод `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state)` активити:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) 
   {
       //находим TextView
       TextView tV=(TextView )this.findViewById(R.id.yours_text_view_id);
       String textFromTextViewToSave=tv.getText();
       state.putString("str1", textFromTextViewToSave);
   }
   ```
2. Для восстановления этого текста при повороте активити в `onCreate` пишем

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle state) 
   {
       //находим TextView
       TextView tV=(TextView )this.findViewById(R.id.yours_text_view_id);
       String textFromTextViewToSave=state.getString("str1");
       tV.setText(textFromTextViewToSave);
   }
   ```
3. Для передачи этих значений в другую активити действуйте по аналогии, сохраняя строки из `TextView` в `Bundle` `Intent`-а, коим запускаете эту активити:

   ```
   Intent intent=new Intent(context, YourAnoterActivity.class);
   intent.putStringExtra("str1", textFromTextViewToSave);
   context.startActivity(intent);
   ```

   , а восстанавливая их в OnCreate этой активити так:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle state) 
   {
        String fromIntent=this.getIntent.getString("str1");
   }
   ```
4. Ещё можно сохранять в `SharePreferences`. Так вы не будете зависеть от жизненного цикла.

   ```
   //сохраняем строку в файл внутренней директории приложения
   SharePreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   pref.edit().putString("key", "value").commit();

   //получаем ранее сохранённые данные
   String savedData=pref.getString("key");
   ```

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне 3 способ нужен. 

Я просто думал, что при уничтожении активити он автоматом все сохраняет в Bundle, так вот чтобы не писать 

    String textFromTextViewToSave=state.getString("str1");

20 раз, можно было бы взять уже готовый, или он пустой? Bundle



Просто мне нужно сохранить то состояние активити, которое есть, а после выключения телефона и включения, и запуска этой программы, чтобы это все вновь появилось, по нажатии загрузить старое активити.


Короче, Спящий режим на компе знаете?) вот то же самое. Можно так?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а, может быть, стоит переопределить `onRestoreInstanceState` вместо мучений в `onCreate`?

Comment: @Futurama, таки придётся пострадать. Можно вместо 20-ти раз один раз сохранить массив строк. Ещё можно переопределить класс TextView и его метод setText(String text), чтоб он сам писал в Bundle. Но это уже путь воина. Ещё можно писать данные в SharedPreferences и брать их оттуда, не пользуясь Bundle. Мой совет - все ваши строки поместить в массив или список, назначать TextView текст оттуда и целиком его в Bundle пихать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а у меня другая идея. Весь этот текст у меня в Adaptere находится. Можно как нибудь сохранить адаптер в файл?

Просто SharedPreferences нет типпа Object..А другой класс для сохранения я не знаю. Если только File.

Не подскажите как сохранить Object типо Adapter?

Comment: @SuperCreeper, лично я отказался от этого метода. Он не всегда работает так, как я ожидаю. К тому же проще сделать свой метод, принимающий Bundle и извлекающий всё нужное. В него можно и из интента передать данные и во фрагменте пользовать. Удобнее так, ИМХО.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне нужно в файл сохранить, Intent не подойдет, понимаете.


Это не вариант, поймите вы меня. У меня в адаптере 60 элементов, в каждом из элементов по 6 view компонентов, из них в некоторых работают 3, в некоторых 2, в некоторых все 6.

Есть одно решение - это взять класс и переписать его уже под загрузку, но там столько времени убить можно.


Попытался я, короче, сохранить через ObjectOutputStream, так в итоге я получил пустой listView.

Comment: @Futurama, если тект в адаптере, то лучше всего, думаю, подойдёт SharedPreferences. Они не зависят от жизненного цикла, доступны отовсюду, получаются в рантайме. Велосипедить с сохранением в файл не нужно. И объекты с адаптерами тоже сохранять не нужно.

Comment: @Futurama, обновил ответ с использованием SharedPreferences.

Comment: Я добавил в свой ответ пример с SharedPreferences. Попробуйте его. Писать в файл объекты вам не надо, поверьте. И просто сделать при таком объёме данных не выйдет. У вас должна быть модель данных, кою вы в адаптере пользуете. Её вам и надо сохранить. Кода в любом случае много будет. Даже если всё в файл строкой пихнуть, всё равно парсер к нему писать надо будет. Не изобретайте велосипед. Пользуйте 4-ый вариант из моего ответа или пилите Базу Данных вообще)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а Bundle можно сохранить через ObjectOutputStream и использовать в  другом активити?

Comment: @Futurama, вам это не нужно. Точно не нужно. Пользуйтесь стандартными средствами.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, как же все трудно в этом андроиде. Объект это не объект, модель это не модель, слова это цифры.

А как в Sharepferefence, который вы показали, добавить String str[], чтобы после взять его из файла?

Comment: при повортие экрана данные нужно сохранять только в Bundle. Или фрагмент специальный на худой конец. Никаких Preferences, потому что при каждом повороте будет запись/чтение с диска. а это сильно замедлит работу если данных много.

Comment: @argamidon,
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13ucu3lETlc

Как сохранить масиив?

Массив 1 "фывф" "ыываыыва" "ыываыывафвы" "ыываыывааывыва"
Массив 2 "фывф" "ыываыыва" "ыываыывафвы" "ыываыывааывыва"
Массив 3 "фывф" "ыываыыва" "ыываыывафвы" "ыываыывааывыва"

Как сохранить массив?

Comment: @Futurama видосы мне лень смотреть. А по поводу как сохранить - у объекта bundle есть методы, чем-то похожие на методы интерфейса java.util.Map (если хоть раз работал с ним, то проблем не будет). Берёш свой массив и пихаешь в Bundle с ключом, например, "array1". Ну и достаёшь потом.

Comment: @argamidon, Ну допустим, я впихнул его в Bundle, ура-а-а, как отлично, да вот только если я тел то выключю, то все, эти данные в памяти сохранятются, который раз уже пишу, мне в ФАЙЛ надо, в ФАЙЛ, а не в память

Comment: @Futurama, вот, почитайте тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3877242/3212712
 Там показано как можно сохранять массивы в SharedPreferences. Кратко - писать строки по строке в файл с разванием массива или хранить Set<String>, если API>11. И да, @argamidon прав: если данные восстанавливаете при повороте экрана - юзайте Bundle, если же надо после полной смерти активити восстановить - то SharedPreferences. Если же данные не меняются никогда - то их нужно в Resources пихать. Тогда вообще ничего сохранять и восстанавливать не надо.

Comment: @Futurama тогда используй Preferences/SQLite. Писать файлы вручную с помощью потоков вроде бы в кит-кате имеются проблемы при использовании файловой системы наприямую. Так что да. используй Preferences/SQLite