# Сохранение элементов ListView после перезагрузки приложения

Tags: java, android, listview, activity-life-cycle

Есть приложение, в котором при нажатии на кнопку создаются и добавляются элементы списка ListView. При перезагрузке приложения, они пропадают. Догадываюсь, что нужно использовать БД, и при создании элемента добавлять его в БД, а в методе OnCreate поставить создание списка ListView из элементов в БД(исправьте, если я не прав). Вопрос такой: можно ли сохранять список после перезагрузки приложения НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЯ БД, т.к. в списке будет максимум 10-15 элеметов(это потолок). Б

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У `Activity` есть `onSaveInstanceState`, который срабатывает при закрытии. Переопределите его, чтоб сохранить данные из `ListView`:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);

    // здесь берём данные из адаптера
    // если у вас ArrayAdapter, то будет так
    String[] values = mAdapter.getValues(); 
    savedState.putStringArray("myKey", values);

}
```

А потом в `onCreate` получайте:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String[] values = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("myKey");
        if (values != null) {
           mAdaptor = new MyAdaptor(values);
        }
    }

    [...]

}
```

Comment: а если я использую свой адаптер, унаследованный от Base Adapter. Как взять данные у Base Adaptera, я искал в его стандартных методах, но не нашёл ничего похожего. Самому нужно писать метод?

Comment: Как вы передаёте данные в адаптер? Если свой конструктор: public `class TimeTrackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {ArrayList<TimeRecord> times = new ArrayList<TimeRecord>();


    public TimeTrackAdapter(ArrayList<TimeRecord> times) {this.times  = times ;` то вы можете из своего адаптера получить их.

Comment: @DenisMolodec лучше задайте новый вопрос для такого.

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Вы можете хранить данные разными способами:

1. В [SharedPreferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/400603/17609)
2. Записывая данные в свой файл любого формата.
3. Использовать БД

Также, если вы под "перезагрузкой приложения" имеете в виду пересоздание экрана при его повороте, то вам также поможет инфа по ссылке из п.1 (сохранение данных активити в `Bundle` при поворотах экрана)