# Как получить значения из ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview

Создал адаптер, унаследовав его от ArrayAdapter. Существует список List View, который заполняет пользователь в ручную. Стоит задача, после нового включения приложения(если список ранее составлялся) вывести список на экран.
Адаптер:

```
     public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Info> {

     ArrayList<Info> nameInfo = new ArrayList<Info>();

     public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Info> nameInfo) {
     super(context, 0, nameInfo);


     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     Info data = getItem(position);
     if (convertView == null) {
        convertView =                                                                
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }

    TextView column1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.col1);
    TextView column2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.col2);


    column1.setText(data.par1);
    column2.setText(data.par2);


    return convertView;
    }
   }
```

`

Вот список и адаптер в мэйн активити:

```
    MyAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, nameInfo);

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    lvMain.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
```

Comment: Уточните, что вы имеете в виду под "перезагрузка приложения"? Поворот экрана; выйти, прибить процесс, запустить; удалить-установить? И опишите лучше какое именно поведение дефолтного адаптера вы не получаете в вашей реализации.

Comment: Ты хочешь получить данные чтобы при закрытие приложения их сохранять? А что используешь в качестве источника данных? Список или еще что-то?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб @jangorussia мой адаптер, унаследованный от Base Adapter`a  создает список listview и заполняет его данными, которые вводит пользователь. При выходе из приложения (onDestroy) список Listview пропадает. Я хочу сохранить данные, чтоыб при следующем открытии приложения (onCreate) список оставался таким, каким он был до закрытия. Какие способы можно использовать?

Comment: @DenisMolodec, вот по ссылке выше посмотрите. Ответ на ваш вопрос: SharedPreferences или БД или сохранение/чтение данных из к-л файла.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб тут в другом вопрос)

Comment: @Suvitruf, всё же, щитаю, моя интерпретация задачи ТС вернее) Как я понял надо данные в списке восстановить даже после, например, перезагрузки девайса. А это надо или чрез БД или чрез преференсы делать. Как я и писал в ответе на вопрос-дубликат. Где мы с вами уже отвечали на этот вопрос также по разному интерпретировав задачу... Замкнутый круг получается)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так это в прошлом вопросе было )

Comment: @Suvitruf, мне кажется, всё же, что оба вопроса реально об одном и том же. Да и обе интепретации как раз таки, вроде, даже имеют ответ в том вопросе... Я запутался( Но на том, что это таки дубликат, всё же настаиваю. =)

Answer (score 1):

Определите метод на получением айтемов `getItems`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Info> {

   List<Info> nameInfo = new ArrayList<Info>();

   public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Info> nameInfo) {
     super(context, 0, nameInfo);


   }

   public List<Info> getItems(){
        return nameInfo ;
   }
   [...]
}
```

Ну и как я в [прошлом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476125/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-listview-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) вашем вопросе описывал:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);

    // здесь берём данные из адаптера
    List<Info> items = mAdapter.getItems();
    savedState.putParcelableArrayList("my_data", items);

}
```

Для этого ещё в вашем классе `Info` надо реализовать [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) интерфейс.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, times и items это разные переменные или это опечатка?

Comment: @DenisMolodec опечатка )

Comment: Понятно. Дело в том, что список создается в основной активити и заполняется пользователем(т.е. нигде не хранится), а мой адаптер это отдельных класс. Задача как раз состоит в том, чтобы добавленные элементы пользователем сохранялись и при следующем включении приложения оставались в списке.

Comment: @DenisMolodec добавьте в вопрос код, как вы это делаете. Иначе сложно что-то посоветовать.

Comment: Изменил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @DenisMolodec обновил ответ

Comment: В последнем блоке, Вы используете список List  -  List<Info> items = mAdapter.getItems(); 
Но затем, вы упаковываете  "putParcelableArrayList" используя ArrayList, так и должно быть?

Comment: @DenisMolodec да, так как `ArrayList` реализует интерфейс `List`.

Comment: В главном активити не виден метод getItems(), хотя он реализован в адаптере и указан в  классе Info в Parcelable.. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, нужно чтобы сохранялся ListView после выхода из приложения.

Тогда лучше использовать ArrayAdapter. В onDestroy (А лучше в onPause) вытащить из него ArrayList, преобразовать его в массив и сохранить в SharedPrefences.

При загрузке из SharedPrefences доставать массив, из него сделать ArrayList и из него создать адаптер.