# Как сохранить программно добавленный текст в LinearLayout. Android

Tags: java, android

```
public void someText(String message) {

    TextView message = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    message.setText(message);
    messageLayout.addView(message);
}
```

Есть у меня такой метод, добавляет в LinearLayout новую цифру, при каждом нажатии кнопки. Вот только не могу разобраться, как это сохранить? Все слетает даже при повороте устройства. Недавно начал осваивать андроид. Читал про SharedPreference, но там сохранение ключ-значение. А как сохранить, чтобы Layout открывался сразу с уже добавленными ранее цифрами (addView(message))?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы все сохранялось только при перевороте?

Comment: И при закрытии - открытии приложения тоже.

Comment: 1. Не добавляйте кучу `TextView`. Добавляйте текст в один `TextView`. 2. Когда надо сохранить текст, забирайте его из TextView, и сохраняйте в `SharedPreferences`. При старте приложения - загружайте его оттуда

Comment: Я планирую использовать gravity, чтобы цифры появлялись по очереди, то слева, то справа. Поэтому куча TextView.

Comment: Вообще SharedPreferences это единственный способ сохранения информации в андроид?

Comment: Не единственный, конечно. Погуглите, вы найдте может 1000, а может 100 000 способов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам надо сохранять кол-во `TextView` в вашей разметке при повороте активити и даже после полного закрытия приложения, то вам [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/400603/17609), п.4.

Кратко порядок действий таков:

1. В `onSaveInstanceState` методе активити вам надо получить всех детей вашего `LinearLayout` методом `ViewGroup#getChildAt(int index)`
2. Пробежаться по ним циклом, скастовать к `TextView` и получить из них их текст.
3. Создать массив/список типа `String` и поместить в него текст всех `TextView`
4. Сохранить в `SharePreferences` этот список/массив.
5. В `onCreate` методе активити проверить есть ли в `SharePreferences` сохранённый массив/список строк и восстановить его. После это циклом по нему пробежаться и добавить в вашу разметку по `TextView` на каждую строку в массиве/списке и сприсвоить им соответствующий текст.

---

В принципе можно и просто через `Bundle` попробовать, есть даже метод восстановления данных после перезагрузки девайса, но я не знаю вызовется ли он при простом прибитии приложения системой ли/юзером

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать куда копать. Я еще подумал, может добавить в этот же метод, после addView, например, чтобы он новую строку в SharePreference сразу записывал. Как думаете? Есть в этом смысл?

Comment: @Владимир, смысла особого в этом не вижу. Если как я предложил, записывать данные в `onSaveInstanceState`, то сохраняться данные будут каждый раз при повороте экрана, сворачивании приложения или прибитии его системой. А так-то можно как угодно, лишь бы это было оправданно.

Comment: @Владимир, кстати, если мой ответ решает поставленную перед вами задачу, ту, что в вопросе заявлена, то вы можете отметить его "Верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа.

Comment: Вот с четвертого пункта у меня проблемы, никак не могу найти способ сохранить массив или список в SharedPreferences, чтобы воспользоваться пятым пунктом. Так-то крутое решение, а как сделать не могу додуматься.

Comment: @Владимир, для этого есть метод `putStringSet` принимающий ключ-строку и `Set<String>`. Вместо сохранения сета вы можете,  принципе массив/список преобразовать в строку, разделив его элементы, например, запятыми и сохранять строку. А после её извлечения можно эту строку обратно в массив/список преобразовать, разрезав по заданному вами разделителю.

Answer (score 0):

Вот посмотрите [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php#save) хорошо объясняется про SharedPreferences, может поможет вам, и чтоб при повороте не слетало все в манифесте добавьте к активити `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"`

Comment: запрет пересоздания активити при повороте устройства - худшее из того, как можно решить "проблему". Очень плохая практика.

Comment: может быть, я поделился тем что мне помогло )