# Как правильно сохранять "Ленту"

Tags: android, recyclerview

Добрый день. У меня в приложении есть "новостная лента"(`RecyclerView`, который заполняется адаптером. При `pull`-e добавляются новые элементы в `recyclerview`). При переходе с этого фрагмента на другой и обратно - весь список пропадает и загрузка списка повторяется.

**Вопрос:** как правильно сохранять список, чтобы каждый раз не загружать заново? На примере приложений Vk, Pikabu и т.д. загруженная лента всегда сохраняется, если попереключать экраны или просто выйти-зайти в приложение.

**Возможное решение:** Можно сохранять все данные в БД, при `pull`-е добавлять новые строчки в БД, но мне кажется там используется какой-то другой механизм.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400599/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) А вообще да - в БД надо пихать.

Comment: про `SharePreferences`, я знаю. Значит всё таки БД.. А какой объём строк должен хранится в БД для ленты? 100 строк? Допустим, если добавлять при обновлении 20 и удалять нижние 20 строк в БД

Comment: Да хоть 10 000)

Comment: @Denis422, глупый вопрос про кол-во строк. Так как можете хранить хоть все. Как вариант, вы можете добавить функционал очистки бд/"кеша"))