# Передать данные между классами

Tags: java, android, классы, передача-данных

Есть два класса. В первом по нажатии кнопки открываем другой, передавая при этом строку. На деле, после нажатия, приложение крашится.

```
 public class Levels2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button level1;
    private String text="1";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.levels2_activity);
        level1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.level1);
        level1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
 public void onClick(View v) {
    text="lkggusbki bq ogkqegy sbej sk ogbhpse oapite pij rbkjbvenqbsy. ckqqbg cueg okhruqsbki bi abtaen-biokhe okuisnbeq pij sae runibit kc rbkhpqq bi gkwen-biokhe okuisnbeq pookuisq ckn 85% kc pbnrknie lpnsbougpse lkggusbki.";
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.level1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Game.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


}
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public class Game extends Activity {
Levels2Activity Level;
String textG;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textG=Level.getText();
    textView.setText(textG);

}
```

}

---

Если правильно понял, то вот лог ошибки
01-23 16:36:04.477 2035-2035/com.example.user.krypto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.user.krypto, PID: 2035
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.krypto/com.example.user.krypto.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2193)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.example.user.krypto.Game.onCreate(Game.java:24)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Напишите текст ошибки.

Comment: Просто "В приложении произошла ошибка"

Comment: Так не пойдет. На вкладке Logcat в Android-Studio найдите текст возникающей ошибки. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: @МаврютинВасилий, вот тут `textG=Level.getText();` у вас NPE, т.к. переменная `Level` `null`. Так как вы пытваетесь - нельзя делать. Только одна активити одновремнно в системе может существовать (быть в фокусе/быть активной). (ну, если не учитывать несколько приложений на экране). Вам надо через Intent данные передавать.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @МаврютинВасилий, если один из ответов помог в решении проблемы, вы можете отметить его "верным" нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут `textG=Level.getText();` у вас `NPE`, т.к. переменная `Level` `null`. Так как вы пытаетесь - нельзя делать. Только одна активити одновремнно в системе может существовать (быть в фокусе/быть активной). (ну, если не учитывать несколько приложений на экране). Вам надо через `Intent` данные передавать.

См 3 пункт ответа тут: [Сохранение и загрузка состояния Activity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/400603/17609)